# How to use a number stored in a variable in an awk command

Tags: bash, awk

I am attempting to have the script grab a random record from a file. The file has 10 total records.
Not sure why what I currently have is not working.
(I have  ``around what n is equal to)

```
n=expr $RANDOM % 10 + 1 
awk 'BEGIN{RS = "%"} NR==$n' pathToFile
```

If I substitute `$n` for any number `1-10` there are no issues.

Comment: Use `n=$(( RANDOM % 10 + 1))`; `expr` is mostly obsolete for arithmetic in POSIX.

Answer (score 2):

You can generate the random number within `awk` to avoid quoting challenges:

```
awk -v min=1 -v max=10 'BEGIN{srand() 
     n=int(min+rand()*(max-min+1))
}
#... the rest of the awk ...'
```

If you want to print a random record:

```
awk -v min=1 -v max=10 'BEGIN{srand() 
n=int(min+rand()*(max-min+1))
} 
NR==n {print; exit}' file
```

Or, you can generate and assign on the `awk` command line:

```
$ awk -v n=$(expr $RANDOM % 10 + 1) 'BEGIN{ print n }'
```

Or,

```
$ echo $n
7
$ awk -v n="$n" 'BEGIN{ print n }'
7
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work the way you want:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS = "%"} NR=="'"$n"'"' /folder/file
```

Note that the only difference from your code is the extra `"'" "'"` around the variable.